# Handling security check in cypress

Tags: cypress

How we can handle the security check window in cypress in which we need to enter a text(shown in another label) in a input box. Please see the screen shot for your reference.

This is related Cypress Automation testing.[security check window screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYWuR.jpg)

I am unable to find the solution to handle this in cypress.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible programmatically. Otherwise, it would be easy for robots to pretend they aren't.

From what I have seen, as you need in any case to log in first, you can have a special role for these E2E users and it should skip this step for them.

For example, the problem could be pretty similar [here](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/4084).